# How to find out how many suggested edits I approved

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Does anybody know how many suggested edits I have approved?

I have privileges to edit anywhere. But some users who edit questions or answers don't have their edits applied for that question/answer immediately. They must be approved by two users who have that privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the information you're looking for is on the "reviews" section of your "activity" tab:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/760489/pratik?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of each edit suggestion summary page, there are some stats for each reviewer. E.g. from  [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/160482):

[image: reviewer stats]

You can also browse the list of suggested edits you've approved/rejected [in your profile under the activity/reviews tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760489/pratik?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

At present, AFAIK there isn't a way to determine how many of your approvals/rejections were actually applied and how many were overruled. See: [Hit rate for approval/rejection of suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110719/hit-rate-for-approval-rejection-of-suggested-edits)