# Help users discover and learn from the results of their edit suggestions

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

This is a (hopefully improved) version of [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) which tries to address the issues raised in that discussion.

If we expect reviewers to improve, they have to somehow discover which of their suggestions were found helpful and which were not. I think we could do this relatively subtly by placing a number next to or in place of the "Review" link (depending on whether they have review privileges):

[image: edit verdict indicator]

This number would reflect any new verdicts on their edit suggestions, whether approved or rejected, which they haven't seen yet. Including accepts and rejections provides both positive and negative feedback, and reduces the "you suck" factor which Jeff was concerned about. The tooltip would be something like "N of your edit suggestions have been reviewed. Click here for details".

Clicking would take you to a page like this:

[image: crude mockup]

the important points are:

- both accepted and rejected are shown; it's not just "you suck"
- rejections include links to explanations so they can find out exactly what was wrong and hopefully see some examples of doing it right. Also explanations of things like "reviewing is expensive, so don't make trivial edits"
- shows reviewer comments so they can see the helpful messages I've been writing for apparently no reason
- It also indicates when an edit was improved, with a link to the improved revision so they can see how they could make their edits even better

It we wanted to tilt the page even further towards positive reinforcement we could add progress bars towards the relevant badges. Perhaps reviewer comments could be allowed for any outcome--accepted, improved, or rejected for any reason--to allow positive feedback there as well.

Comment: I like it. The more feedback I get the better. I like feedback.

Comment: Don't polish turds? Ha, I should adopt that phrase.

Comment: @ani it's actually one of [Jeff's mantras](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77683/151987)