# Get own count stats for suggested edits

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I guess that I may get a "duplicated question" but it's welcome, I can not find an answer ... How an user can access to his own accumulated review suggested edit stats (**total number of approved and total number of rejected** by me, not just total reviewed)?

I can access the Suggested Edits - History tab but it doesn't show totals. Is there any way to get this info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the [history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) or the [reviews tab in your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews) and open a suggested edit you reviewed (if you have >10k reputation, you'll see suggested edit reviews by *all* people in the first link).

[image]

Click on the 'suggested edit' link, which will show you the review actions for this particular review.

[image]

Click '(more)', and then more statistics will be shown (both for you, for other reviewers and the user who suggested the edit).

[image]

This information is available **only** for this particular review queue. It's possible to get more detailed information (i.e. distinguished between 'Improve Edit' and 'Reject and Edit') with [this userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307576/295232) by @rene.

Comment: That's the number of total reviewed. How can I distinguish between approved and rejected?

Comment: @RubioRic sorry, not enough coffee yet.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I need to put some time in to make that a proper US, with a decent UI ....

Comment: Perfect! Thanx a lot!